# Discord.net how to change channel topic

Tags: discord.net

Hey how do I change SocketTextChannel topic?

```
SocketTextChannel channel = arg.Channel as SocketTextChannel;
```

Comment: You can refer to the [Docs example](https://docs.stillu.cc/api/Discord.TextChannelProperties.html)

Comment: https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/api/Discord.WebSocket.SocketTextChannel.html